# Java method with unknown parameter type

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm new to Java.

There is repeating code in multiple files in a project I'm working on.
Object types can be Thing1, Thing2, Thing3 etc.
So the code looks like:

```
if (Thing1.getStuff() instanceof String) {
  myObj.setString("Hello");
} else {
  myObj.setString("World");
}
```

I want to extend myObj with a class and method to handle this, as such:

```
public class myObj extends DoStuff {...}
```

--

```
class DoStuff {
    public String doThis(*WHAT_TYPE_TO_USE* input) {
        var String = input.myMethod(); // I need to call method.
        return "String after some logic";
    }
}
```

Which should allow me to run:

```
 myObj.doThis("Something");
```

However, I can't specify input to be a specific type in the method as it could be Thing1, Thing2 etc. Also, Thing1 and Thing2 can't be dynamically imported, can they? How can I run myMethod (which exists in Thing1 and Thing2)?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused regarding what is your underlying need. But I sense **interfaces** (or abstraction mechanism) is what you need.

Comment: @kleopatra I don't think it is unrelated. `Thing1.getStuff()` looks like a static method and they say `Thing1` and `Thing2` are types. So they're lacking details, that naming conventions could help clarify

Comment: @matt true (read: I fully agree :), though we can't really know whether getStuff is static or just sloppy snippets, but we do know the `class doStuff` and `void DoThis` are indeed naming violations :)

Comment: @matt Thank you. getStuff is a static method that I have no control over. You can call it a sloppy snippet, for sure, but the idea is to suggest that I do need the ability to call methods on Thing1/Thing2 etc. I'm trying to keep the focus on what I see as important. Sorry if I left detail out.
About naming conventions, yes, I'm paraphrasing everything here. My code looks different, I'm just trying to get the point of the logic here. But thank you.

Comment: If you're paraphrasing, then absolutely make sure you're using naming conventions. Please switch the name of your interface to DoStuff and your method to doThis. It doesn't change the effects of the code, but it helps us understand. I have trouble thinking of an example where a static method `Thing1.getStuff()` needs to be followed by `instanceof`. Is `getStuff` going to change during runtime?

Comment: @matt I've changed that, thank you. Yes, it can change during runtime. Not my code, and I'm only able to affect some of it. I have no ability to edit Thing1/Thing2 either, which makes things tricky.

Comment: Does input have to be Thing1, Thing2 etc? In that case you cannot really do anything because you want to access the static methods. You could take `String doThis(Object input)` where input is the result of `ThingX.getStuff()`. That would help you consolidate the logic.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that what I'm hoping for is unrealistic due to these restrictions and this repeating code is inevitable.

Answer (score 2):

You need your `Thing` classes to implement a common interface such as

```
public interface Thing {
  public String myMethod();
}

public class Thing1 implements Thing {
  ...
}
```

If they don't have a common supertype, then the two `myMethod` methods are *unrelated*. The fact that they have the same name is irrelevant to Java; they're distinct methods defined in distinct classes. You *can* access them with reflection shenanigans, but then you're giving up a lot of type safety (at that point, you would just take an `Object` and trust the user to provide a value of the correct type; it's ugly and messy and I don't recommend it).

If the classes in question are third-party classes (i.e. that you don't control) and don't implement a common interface, then you need the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). Basically, you define a new class that *does* implement the interface and wraps an instance of the original.

```
public class Thing1Adapter implements Thing {
  private Thing1 impl;

  public Thing1Adapter(Thing1 impl) {
    this.impl = impl;
  }

  @Override
  public String myMethod() {
    return this.impl.myMethod();
  }

}

...

DoThis(new Thing1Adapter(myThing1));
```